# Dropping HTML elements into a SVG structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have the following picture that depicts part of an application:

[image]

I want to be able to drag the disabled input boxes into the matrix.

The behaviour I want is:

1) When I drag the input box:
    1.1. It changes into a translucid color;
    1.2. After it's dragged into the matrix, the cell into which the input box is dropped into will change color;

2) The dragged input box should disappear from the right menu;

I am doing this with different technologies: the matrix in blue is an SVG picture composed of several rectangles, generated programatically with AngularJS/Javascript and read from a database and the input boxes are also generated programatically with jQuery;

AFAIK, it's somehow complicated to integrate SVG and HTML for dragNdrop events so any help will be appreciated. Here is the code:

Code for JQuery and generation of input boxes on the right:

```
 $scope.PopulateQuestionsExpert=function() {
       var N=$scope.perguntas.length;
        alert("Num of questions is "+ N);
        var targetDiv = $("#questionsExpert");
        targetDiv.html("");
        for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            var auxi = "q"+i;
            //  targetDiv.append($("<input />"));
            targetDiv.append(" <div class=\"input-group input-group-option col-xs-12\">\
            <input id="+ auxi+"  type=\"text\" name=\"option[]\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Add option...\" disabled>\
                <span class=\"input-group-addon input-group-addon-remove\">\
                <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></span>\
                </div>");

            document.getElementById(auxi+"").value=$scope.perguntas[i];
            //document.getElementById(auxi+"").setAttribute('draggable', 'true');
        }
        // alert("Finished populate");
        //$("#showq").click(); //HACK
       // angular.element('#showq').trigger('click').trigger('click');
        //VER COMANDOS DE JQUERY QUE USAM MANIPULAÇÃO E COLOCAÇÃO DE ELEMENTOS: INSERT() E INSERTAFTER()

    };
```

The matrix is composed of an array that contains JSON elements similar to this:

```
{"rect":{"x":220,  "y":220,  "width" : 300, "height" : 100}, "info":""}
```

Is there any way to make the input boxes (simple HTML) droppable onto the (SVG) matrix?

Comment: If you want to embed HTML in your SVG, then you will need to use the `<foreignObject>` element.  See other questions on her for how to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add HTML into an SVG directly, well, mostly not. There is the concept of a [foreignObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject).

I'm guessing your better bet is to do a swap. Either when you start dragging the HTML, or when you go to drop the HTML.

SO either:

1. Detect drag on html, hide html, unhide matching svg, start drag on svg.

[OR]

2. Detect drop on currently dragged html, hide html, unhide svg, perform drop on svg.